# Using tab in a QTableView moves two rows at a time

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using a custom delegate for a `QTableView`.  Instead of the default `QLineEdit` editor widget, I want a `QLineEdit` with a combo box next to it.  The custom editor displays properly, by when I'm done typing in the text box and hit tab to move to the next row in the table, it skips the next row and instead starts editing the cell two rows below.  If, instead of using tab, I use the enter key, it moves to the next row as expected.  Can someone explain what is happening with the tab key behavior here?

BTW, my table has two columns and only the second column is editable, hence why the editor should move to the row below.

I made my custom delegate by inheriting from `QStyledItemDelegate` like this:

```
class ParameterDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate {
public:
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyledItemDelegate& option, const QModelIndex& index) {
       QWidget* widget = new QWidget(parent);
       widget->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout());
       widget->layout()->addWidget(new QLineEdit());
       widget->layout()->addWidget(new QComboBox());
       widget->layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
       widget->layout()->setSpacing(0);
       return widget;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be very simple; subclass `QWidget` and reimplement `QWidget::focusNextPrevChild` to return `false`, like this:

```
class MyCustomEditorWidget: public QWidget {
public:
   bool focusNextPrevChild(bool next) {return false;}
};
```

Then change the code in the `QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor` reimplementation to create/return a new instance of `MyCustomEditorWidget`:

```
QWidget* widget = new MyCustomEditorWidget();
//etc.
```